# Proving a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ has a trivial fundamental group.

Tags: algebraic-topology

**Question:** Let $X = X_1 \cup ... \cup X_n$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $X_i$ is convex and $X_i \cap X_j \cap X_k \neq \emptyset$ for all $i, j, k$, then $\pi_1(X, x_0) = \{e\}$ for all $x_0 \in X$.

**My thoughts:** all $X_i$ are path connected, and for $x \in X_i, y \in X_j$ they have a non-empty intersection, so pick a point $z$ in that, and then we can construct a path $x \to z \to y$. This means that $X$ is path connected, so no need to worry about basepoints.

We know that $X_1 \cup X_2 \cup X_3$ has a trivial fundamental group because it is contractible (take $a \in X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3$, then $H_t(x) = tx + (1 - t)a$ is a deformation retract). I don't know how to extend this to $X$ entire. What is the significance of requiring $X_i \cap X_j \cap X_k \neq \emptyset$? I've encountered $X_i \cap X_j \neq \emptyset$ lots of times, but never with 3.

Comment: well one idea is to just do induction on $n$ and to use the same idea.

Comment: Consider three partially overlapping arcs on $S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.  They do not have a point of intersection in common, and $\pi_1(S^1)\neq 1$.  Think of $S^1$ as being an equilateral triangle and $X_i$ being edge number $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: Read the proof of Lemma 1.15 page 35 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf). Since each $X_i$ is convex, the proof you need follows from this lemma.